# Replace image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<div id="show">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR51FTd5w9iwfz_PLnUTUIbYBB0bCX6d3ue1ZSx3SJObNLGECEm"
>
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
    <div id="thumbnail1">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPIzMxDNjQ_x4iUZ6WLo9R32QKCreu8PQGxcRHWmUw4hNcYmiR"
        width="100" height="100">
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnail2">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR51FTd5w9iwfz_PLnUTUIbYBB0bCX6d3ue1ZSx3SJObNLGECEm"
        width="100" height="100">
    </div>
    <div id="thumbnail3">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsplNlIS3zRyy89UxlT5Nwu_Bn7m6w7iqMYXPF9q9MpLOG17XR"
        width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

My **CSS**:

```
#thumbnails div {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid;
}
#thumbnails div:hover {
    color:yellow;
}
```

So, I just want to change the `div #show` with any thumbnails below it when clicked. I've tried it using `jQuery .attr('src', 'url');` but it doesn't work well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PemHv/

Thank you

Comment: `I've tried it using jQuery .attr('src', 'url'); but it doesn't work well.` Huh?

Comment: You should at least post what Javascript you do have in your Fiddle for any of us to help put you on the right track.

Comment: I put my attempt using jQuery on my fiddle, I only knew using .remove() and .attr() and it didn't work, so I remove my .attr()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User `.on()` to assign click event to dom and `.attr()` to get attribute value of `DOM`.

```
$('#thumbnails img').on('click',function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $('#show img').attr('src',src);
});
```

**Explanation**

in above code i assigned `click` event to the images inside `div` with id of `thumbnails` now first get the `src attribute` of the `clicked image` and set it into `src` variable.

then in next line it replace the `src attribute` of image inside `show div`.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PemHv/3/

jQuery:

```
$('img',".thumbnail").click(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('img',$('#show')).attr('src',src);
});
```

HTML (you should use classes):

```
<div id ="show">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR51FTd5w9iwfz_PLnUTUIbYBB0bCX6d3ue1ZSx3SJObNLGECEm" width="200" height="200">
    </div>

<div id="thumbnails">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPIzMxDNjQ_x4iUZ6WLo9R32QKCreu8PQGxcRHWmUw4hNcYmiR" width="100" height="100">
    </div>

<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR51FTd5w9iwfz_PLnUTUIbYBB0bCX6d3ue1ZSx3SJObNLGECEm" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/PemHv/9/

```
$('#thumbnails div').click(function(){
    var path = $(this).find('img').attr("src");
    //console.log(path)
    $('#show img').attr("src", path );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#show')
    .children()
    .on('click', function(event) {
        $(event.target).attr('src', 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPIzMxDNjQ_x4iUZ6WLo9R32QKCreu8PQGxcRHWmUw4hNcYmiR');
    });
```